# A question about reference materials on Einstein field equation

Tags: general-relativity

I am a student majoring in mathematics, my specialization is topology and analysis. I am writing a thesis on the general relativity, and I want to consult about Einstein field equation. I have tried finding and reading some books about general relativity or mathematics of general relativity, but none of them seem satisfying my aspiration. Since I am a mathematics student, I prefer mathematics materials more than theoretical physics materials. I just have a sense of feeling that I am not fit with the way of writing for physicists and physics students in these physics books. A nice reference material for me should have the definitions of the concepts used in the field equation such as curvature tensor, stress-energy tensor, with some derivation of the field equation, and the solving for some special solution of the equation. May you introduce me some such books ? Thanks. Best wishes.

Comment: Have you had any previous exposure to differential geometry?

Comment: Isn't this what nearly any textbook does, from Misner-Thorne-Wheeler to Carroll? Yes, they contain some physical motivation, but usually the bulk of the text is explaining differential geometry of Riemannian manifolds. Then a quick "derivation" of the field equations, often just by noting they are the simplest ones that fit physical desiderata, and then solutions (usually Schwarzschild, FRW cosmologies, and gravitational waves).

Comment: @TimRias yes, I have learnt differential topology, analysis on manifold, a little bit of tensor and pseudo-Riemannian geometry.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that as of the thirtieth edition of the CRC *standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae*, the AMS had "Relativity and Gravitational theory" officially listed as number 83 in their official classification theme. So, you might do better to ask mathematicians about the kind of books they read. Honestly, though, I think you would do well to pay attention to what the physicists have to say about their own subject, you could apply your mathematical insights to that with good effect. I am going to recommend to you Robert Wald's *General Relativity*. Wald's book might not be mathematical enough to you, I am not sure how it ranks overall, however, I have found it to be better than alot of Relativity texts in that regard. Give it a look see.